# Rails article voting restriction in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building a test application in rails, it's a news story voting system to teach myself rails and ruby.

I'm trying to restrict the voting so the user can 'vote up' an article only once on each article. After some research the best way I've found of getting this to work is adding a validation on a vote model which I've create that checks for a duplicate vote entry by that user.

I'm not really after a code example just some advice that this is the best way of breaking this problem down? The active record validates work perfectly but it doesn't feel like a good practice to put so much strain at the database level, but maybe this is completely fine?

Hope this makes sense, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact the right design. In a relational setup, you'll have Stories, Users, and Votes, where Votes have both a user_id and story_id. Enforcing data integrity is ultimately a database constraint, and you can't really know if a user has voted on a story not without going to the database to check. You could keep some kind of higher-level cache to prevent quite as much database access if needed, but doing so now would be a premature optimization. Cross that bridge when you need to.

One thing to consider would be to create a compound unique index of (user_id, story_id) on your votes table. This would have the benefits of backstopping your validation and improving vote lookup speed to an O(log n) operation, which should eliminate much of the time burden. Something else you can do is disallow votes on old stories, and purge any votes records older than a certain age (corresponding to the time at which you disallow voting), which would keep your votes table at a relatively constant size over time, rather than just permitting it to grow forever.